# ASP.Net Web API is not available. If changing to a name other than "weatherforecast"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have created the API in my project using **ASP.Net Web API** and I
change name of `WeatherForecastController.cs` to
`APIController.cs` and chang `"launchUrl": "FETL"` instead of `"launchUrl": "weatherforecast"` in `launchSettings.json`

So I can not run my API, but if I back to use default name as `WeatherForecastController.cs` and `"launchUrl": "weatherforecast"` in `launchSettings.json`, so that can be used.

Why?  And how to solve it?

This is the old *default* of `WeatherForecastController.cs` and `"launchUrl": "weatherforecast"` in `launchSettings.json`

[`"launchUrl": "weatherforecast" in launchSettings.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPYwa.png)
[`WeatherForecastController.cs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewPls.png)
[API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7xk.png)

And this is what I want to rename, but the result is unavailable.

[`"launchUrl": "FETL" in launchSettings.json`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpT7M.png)
[`APIController.cs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee2pv.png)
[API result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExYbT.png)

Comment: Rename controller. If you expand controllers, you will see WeatherForecastController. Url weatherforecast points to that controller without end "Controller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow @vivek nuna suggest

This was what happened.
[`WeatherForecastController.cs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE7Md.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MumpM.png)

And when I renamed it.
[`APIController.cs`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YADDM.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSY8n.png)

Comment: Yes!, I found the problem and it can be solved, it is must be named with the word "Controller" included.

Comment: Like APIController.cs, AController.cs or BController.cs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Route` like this for your controller, you can use your controller name in place of `DefaultController`

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
{
```

And please make sure that you have a GET method defined in the controller, something like this.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "Welcome" };
}
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggest, but the result was the still.

Comment: check in the browser console. are you getting any error?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You need to change the launch auto also

Comment: Did you mean to show the code of the request? I'm confused.

Comment: Can you change the launch url? If no then you need to define the route otherwise change the launch url

Comment: I changed it in "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",

and then I get the error as usual, but if I switch back to using weatherforecast Will be able to use normally